# What is the probability of selecting at least one piece of fruit?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose I have $8$ oranges and $12$ pineapples. I draw $5$ fruit at random (without replacement) from the bag. What is the probability I have at least $1$ orange?

Solution:
The probability of selecting no oranges is $${12 \choose 5}/{20 \choose 5}.$$ Therefore, the probability of selecting at least $1$ orange is $$1- {12 \choose 5}/{20 \choose 5}.$$

Question: What is **wrong** with the following reasoning:
First select one orange. There are $8$ ways to do this. Then select the remaining four fruit. There are ${19 \choose 4}$ ways to do this. So, the probability should be
$$\frac{8 \times {19 \choose 4}}{{20 \choose 5}}.$$

The incorrect way of approaching this problem gives an answer of two, which is clearly wrong. But I am having difficulty precisely articulating where the reasoning goes awry.

Comment: Draw the probability tree of possibilities.

Comment: You get repeats with the second method. For example, suppose you picked the first orange and then the second orange was in the remaining combinations of four out of nineteen. That is the same as picking the second orange as one of the eight ways and then taking the first orange from the rest.

Comment: 1- (12/20 * 11/19 ... 8/16) because is without replacement

Comment: Wrong Method's numerator, $\displaystyle8 \times {19 \choose 4},$ contains a application of the multiplication principle to an operation containing two steps that can be performed in $8$ ways and $19 \choose 4$ ways regardless of how preceding steps are performed; does this actually describe the given operation?

Comment: Imagine there is a small symbol on each orange (orange n°1, n°2 ..;n°8), you will immediatly see that  picking orange-1, then orange-2, or picking orange-2, then orange-1, you count this twice (and probably even more) in your 2nd formula. It is always useful to imagine some small numbers on each object to differenciate them.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have 8 oranges and 12 pineapples. I draw 5 fruit at random (without replacement) from the bag. What is the probability I have at least 1 orange?
$$
\frac{\left(\binom{8}{1}\binom{12}{4}+\binom{8}{2}\binom{12}{3}+\binom{8}{3}\binom{12}{2}+\binom{8}{4}\binom{12}{1}+\binom{8}{5}\binom{12}{0}\right)}{\binom{20}{5}}=\frac{613}{646}.
$$
First select one orange. There are 8 ways to do this. Then select the remaining four fruits. So, the probability should be
$$
\frac{\binom{8}{1}\binom{12}{4}}{\binom{20}{1}\binom{19}{4}}=\frac{33}{646}.
$$

Comment: You should specify that the second calculation is the probability of selecting exactly one orange.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig, "First select one orange." is specified already.

Comment: In your second calculation, you are calculating the probability of selecting *exactly* one orange.  However, you did not state this.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig, Exactly one orange and the remaining four fruits.